# In Javascript, how can one verify a signed message using a provided monero address?

Tags: address, messagesigning

Is there a library to verify a signed message with a provided monero address in Javascript only? I'm trying to build an app in javascript that takes a signed message and verifies that a particular address owns that message.

If there is no javascript library that can do this. Where can I start to figuring out how to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Lugi's repo](https://github.com/luigi1111/xmr.llcoins.net). There's a page `sign.html` which will have the code you need.

> generates and verifies signatures on arbitrary data using one of your account private keys (spend key or view key)

The same tools are hosted here for experimenting: https://xmr.llcoins.net/sign.html

Comment: so i cannot verify a message with just the address alone?

Comment: Did you even check out the site?

Comment: i did what i meant was just using the public monero address only to do the verification. your answer says "using one of your account private keys". I'm not going to have the private keys of these public addresses. all I'm going to have is the monero public address and just the signed message.

Comment: If you opened the link you'd see the address is made part of the signature and the signature is produced by either of the private keys.

Comment: I'm guessing the private key is for generation, not for verification.